# Pre defined text in Details field in Work Item TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem, workitem

we want the details field of our work items to have a pre defined text. Since the fields have the attribuded HTML, is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can customize the field to have a default value ([Define a default value or copy a value to a field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194948.aspx#Anchor_1)) and you can use html code for the default value:

> ```
>  <FIELD name="Repro Steps" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps" type="HTML">
>     <REQUIRED />
>     <DEFAULT from="value" value="&lt;b&gt;Environment tested:&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br/&gt;foo&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;b&gt;Steps:&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;ol&gt;&lt;li&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ol&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;b&gt;Actual results:&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;b&gt;Expected results:&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br/&gt;" /></FIELD>
> ```

Comment: Thanks, truly working. Tried base html without CSS "<table><tr><th></th><th></th></tr></table>", but 255 chars limit :-/